# How to know I have SQL installed?

Tags: sql-server

This is what I have if I search for **SQL** in my installed programs:

[image]

and if I try localhost then I get the connection error.

I **CAN** successfully connect to online database we have at work but for practicing I want to use my own local DB and I can't connect to it?

[image]

Comment: Try using your computer name as the Server name.

Comment: Thanks, yes I did that too ... same error .. I also looked at "Services" but did NOT see a SQL Server kind of service to even "start" it .. there was just SQL Server Browser service

Comment: Then it appears that you do not have a local database engine installed. You can just run the program SQLServerManager12.msc (for 2014). Refer to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/997663/where-is-sql-configuration-manager-in-windows-10) for more options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have an entry "Microsoft SQL Server xxxx" in your `Start Menu > Programs`. If so, you have some bits of SQL Server installed.

If you have this folder - try to find the "Configuration Tools > SQL Server xxxx Configuration Manager", and launch it.

If it open, it should show you a screen something like this:

[image]

In the "SQL Server Services" tab, find the entries labelled "SQL Server (xxxx)" - if you don't find any --> you **do not** have SQL Server installed.

If you find some - is their "State = running" ? If not - SQL Server is installed, but not running, so you cannot connect to it.

The value in brackets after "SQL Server" is the **instance name** - `MSSQLSERVER` stands for the default (unnamed) instance which you should be able to connect to using `.`, `(local)` (including the parenthesis!), or `localhost`.

If you see any other string, that's the instance name that needs to be used for connecting to it - in my case e.g. `SQL2014`, so I can connect to that instance using `.\SQL2014`, `(local)\SQL2014`, or `localhost\SQL2014`.

Comment: Thanks for detailed info. Yep I had searched for SQL Server kind of "service" in Windows Services but nothing found. So it appears that I just don't have SQL Server Engine installed and on this laptop so far they have just installed SSMS .